# Using Bootstrap 3 from Clojurescript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, clojurescript

I would like to have a React Bootstrap JavaScript file in my markup, and then use Bootstrap components from Clojurescript. I understand this simple approach (not using a cljs library) should be possible. However I am stuck at the beginning with a problem even loading the static html page.

The body section of the page looks like this:

```
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.28.2/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/devcards.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

The `react-bootstrap.min.js` file is being loaded/executed and returning this error in the browser console:

```
Navigated to http://localhost:3449/cards.html
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClass' of undefined
PanelGroup.js:7 
bootstrap 35d834203e0f472d9612:19
react-bootstrap.min.js:7481
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully there will be a better answer than this very direct one. I discovered including all the files recommended [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html) gets me past that particular error.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.28.2/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But is this really the best way to go about it with ClojureScript? No! React is normally already included (via Reagent or Om) as part of a ClojureScript development stack. Seems like I'm discovering why it is best to stick with libraries for Bootstrap.

Comment: React isn't included with ClojureScript unless you are using a ClojureScript library that brings it in (Re-agent, Om, etc).

Comment: When targeting the browser it would be unusual not to include React somehow - React and ClojureScript go together. So to then be having React as a JavaScript library as above would be including it twice. Not a good direction to be going in. Also having React already compiled with GC compiler gives dead code elimination that the above (directly including JavaScript files) does not give you.

Comment: I'm not saying that you should import it twice, I'm saying that Clojurescript doesn't ship with React built in. A fresh `lein new cljs` project won't include React until you require a dependency that brings it in. Alternatively, you can include it as a script then use it with the js/ interface.

Comment: Probably best if I tidy up my wording then. I never meant to say that that React is built in to ClojureScript. My answer effectively imports React twice (as almost all cljs browser targeting environments (Reagent or Om) already have React). So I am saying my answer is a poor one for that reason.

Comment: "using advanced optimisations on React just breaks it" https://clojurians.slack.com/archives/reagent/p1453904258000212. This means that React is 'normal Javascript' rather than 'GC compiler amenable Javascript', so my comment above about dead code elimination was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bootstrap project that uses Om.

https://github.com/racehub/om-bootstrap

Comment: Great to know about if you are using Om (but not say a Reagent single atom library such as reframe or Rum), or even Om Next.